# What WINAPI responsible to detect keyboard state when 'parsing' WM_CHAR?

Tags: c++, winapi

For example, if you press 2 on your keyboard at the notepad it generates `WM_CHAR` with x `charCode`, if you hold shift and press 2 it generates y `charCode`.

What `WINAPI` is responsible for detecting the keyboard state to 'build' the WM_CHAR according to it?

(obs: sorry don't speak english well)

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard messages are queued in the receiving thread's message queue. Each thread maintains its own keyboard state machine. The translation of individual key messages into `WM_CHAR` messages is handled by the `TranslateMessage()` API function when called in the thread's message loop. This is stated as much in the [`WM_CHAR` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char):

> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a `WM_KEYDOWN` message is translated by the `TranslateMessage` function.

Read [About Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input) for more details, particularly [Keystroke Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-messages) and [Character messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#character-messages).

Comment: When i send `WM_KEYDOWN` `Shift` and another `WM_KEYDOWN` with: `2` followed by `WM_CHAR` `@` it works correctly, however when i hold CTRL at the same it doesn't, how i could "skip" the window from reading the CTRL and firing the message as being sent?

Comment: @Raja [you can't simulate keyboard input by sending messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: So its not possible what i asked? even hooking the apis?

Comment: @Raja you didn't explain what you are trying to accomplish in the first place. I answered your original question as it was asked. If you have further questions, please post them separately.